# Getting unexpected result when trying to remove element from array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm new to C and I'm trying to work through a function within a program that would remove the integer 5 from an array of varying length, also shortening the array afterwards to accommodate. `a[0]` is the element in the array that determines that array's length. `v` is the element that would be removed from the array. Within the remaining code, as well as all the other details, this is taken into account.

The following is the code I have written for the function:

```
void delete_set(int v, int a[])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < a[0]; i++)
        if (a[i] == v)
        {
            for(j = i; j < a[0]; j++)
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
            a[0] = a[0] - 1;
        }
}
```

So, I'm unsure if you would need to see the rest of the code outside of this function for it to make sense, but my problem is this. Whatever I set `a[i] ==` to (in the if statement), if the length of the array read in is exactly that number, I get an unexpected answer. However, for any other read in array's length, I get expected (correct) results. Any change in coding would have to be done within the function, as that is how this problem was presented to me.

Thanks, and sorry for the lengthy post (if it is). I'm not too used to using forums.

Comment: Is a[0] the length of the array including a[0]?

Comment: `if (a[i] == v)` --> `while(a[i] == v)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip the element holding the length, it should be:
for `(i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! You couldn't imagine how long I was stuck working through this lol. Or maybe you could ...

Comment: @Modrummer I once spent a week trying to find a `,` that should have been a `;`.  A colleague walked in, took one look and said "You know you have a comma instead of a semi-colon right?"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your outer loop is looking at `a[0]` as if it were an actual element of your array (and not the length). Try:

```
for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++) ...
```

Notice also that I used `<=` there because if you have three elements, they would be in `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`. If you don't do this, you will have trouble removing the element which happens to be last in your array.

Comment: Good catch on the `<=`

Answer (score 0):

If `a[0]` is the length of the array, should you remove it?  Without saving it first?  Also, shouldn’t you be shifting all the elements of the original array?  Only once?

You should try refactoring your algorithm.  Hint: you need only one loop with a current index and the number of elements removed.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop also has a problem as it goes off the end of the array.  You need to swap the placement of changing the number of elements with the for loop that copies the elements.  Assuming that a[0] is the length of the array which includes a[0] then we have the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < a[0]; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == v) {
        a[0] = a[0] - 1;
        for (int j = i; j < a[0]; ++j) {
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
        }
    }
}
```